# Using Sony Camera API on AndroidWear

Tags: wear-os, sony, sony-smartwatch, sony-camera-api

I want to create an app that can start and stop recording from a Sony AS100VR camera using camera remote API.

I can get the same working from my nexus using a direct Wifi connection, but when I establish a direct wifi connection from my Sony smartwatch, it fails at the SSDP detection stage.

It's definitely connected to the camera, SSID over Wifi, but it can't detect it.

I have tried playing with retries and timeout values, but I have sort of run out of ideas.

it's falling into the catch  catch (InterruptedIOException e) with a java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP Mulitcast is not available on smartwatch, so SSDP discovery fails.

There is a **fail-safe** choice for any UPnP based application, that is:

As in most case, the resource URL structure keeps unchanged except `IP Address`, so when SSDP discovery failed, let user directly input the `IP Address` (maybe in form of UI Picker) and get "DeviceDescription.xml" or something else then setup services.

Comment: Many thanks.  I will remove the discovery code and implement a fixed connection.

Comment: Many thanks. I now have something that sorta works (using a fixed device URL), many layout problems to fix, but managed to control recordings on my Sony actioncam on my Sony Smartwatch3.

It's just a shame Sony weren't interested in doing this, but then I guess they want to sell LiveView remotes...

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the CameraRemoteSampleApp that comes with the Camera Remote API SDK?  I assume when you say Smartwatch you mean you are using a Sony SmartWatch 3 that supports a direct WiFi connection?  If so, you should be able to modify the sample app with minimal changes and run it on the SW3.