# Sony Camera Api on Android Wear

Tags: camera, udp, wear-os, sony, sony-camera-api

I created a Android Wear application that can control a supported Sony Camera using the Sony Camera Api. I got it all working(recoring, liveview etc.), so i wanted to focus on the "connecting" thing.

As said in the following question i connect to the Sony Camera using a hardcoded ip-address because UDB Multicast is not supported on Android Wear:
[Using Sony Camera API on AndroidWear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764192/using-sony-camera-api-on-androidwear)

I know this is not best practice, so i wanted to know if there is something else then SSDP to get the ip-address from the Sony Camera.

Is there a list of ip-addresses per device, or is there a another protocol to find out, or will it be soon supported in Android Wear? Questions i can not answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but the alternative to using SSDP on the watch is to use it on the phone.

You would of course, use the paired smartphone to discover the camera using SSDP. And, the smartphone would share the camera's URL with the watch.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for your answer! I implemented this solution yesterday afternoon.

I discover the camera on the smartphone and then send the URL and current WiFi network to the Android Wearable to let the Android Wearable easily connect with the Sony Camera!

Comment: Nice answer i habe Problems with UDP. Goind to test SSDP thos afternoon.